# how to convert 500 meters to pixels on map in esri js?

Tags: javascript, esri, meter

i need to convert 500 meters to pixels on map in esri js but i really don't succeed, i read in esri documants but i couldn't find something which can help me 
**also i tried many calculations like:**

```
currExtent.getWith() / map.width * 500
```

**and**

```
scaleUnits.getUnitValueForSR(map.spatialreference) * 500
```

but non of them worked.
maybe some one know a better calculation for this job?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need `toScreenGeometry` method of ["esri/geometry/screenUtils"](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.geometry.screenutils-amd.html) module to do that.

> `toScreenGeometry(map.extent, map.width, map.height, your500MetersGeometry)`

The `toScreenGeometry` method will return geometry with coordinates are screen coordinates (pixel) based on your current map extent, and position on the screen.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. but i need the 500 meters to pixel for heat map blur radius, so the function is not what i need